# Airflow systemd scheduler not working

Tags: airflow

I got the webserver to work properly, and my airflow-scheduler.service file starts the scheduler and it finds my dags etc. However, tasks are not running:

I see an error message about /bin/sh

```
ERROR - failed to execute task Command 'exec bash -c run'
```

I have my sysconfig file:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/envs/airflow_env/bin/airflow
AIRFLOW_CONFIG=/mnt/var/airflow/airflow.cfg
AIRFLOW_HOME=/mnt/var/airflow
```

And my airflow-scheduler.service file:

```
#!/bin/bash
[Unit]
Description=Airflow scheduler daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service
Wants=postgresql.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/envs/airflow_env/bin/airflow scheduler
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the journalctl record which shows the bash error I am getting:

```
[2017-10-30 18:36:13,764] {base_executor.py:50} INFO - Adding to queue: airflow run user_presence_raw_etl transform_raw_user_presence 2017-10-30T14:00:00 --local -sd /mnt/var/airflow/dags/bin/user_p
Oct 30 18:36:13  airflow[4742]: [2017-10-30 18:36:13,765] {jobs.py:1443} INFO - Heartbeating the executor
Oct 30 18:36:13  airflow[4742]: [2017-10-30 18:36:13,783] {local_executor.py:45} INFO - LocalWorker running airflow run user_presence_raw_etl transform_raw_user_presence 2017-10-30T14:00:00 --local -sd /mnt/var/airflow/dags/bin/us
Oct 30 18:36:13  airflow[4742]: /bin/sh: 1: exec: bash: not found
Oct 30 18:36:13  airflow[4742]: [2017-10-30 18:36:13,865] {local_executor.py:52} **ERROR - failed to execute task Command 'exec bash -c 'airflow run** user_presence_raw_etl transform_raw_user_presence 2017-10-30T14:00:00 --local -sd /mnt/var/airf
Oct 30 18:36:14  airflow[4742]: [2017-10-30 18:36:14,786] {jobs.py:1407} INFO - Heartbeating the process manager
Oct 30 18:36:14  airflow[4742]: [2017-10-30 18:36:14,786] {dag_processing.py:559} INFO - Processor for /mnt/var/airflow/dags/bin/prod/hourly_agent_dag.py finished
Oct 30 18:36:14  airflow[4742]: [2017-10-30 18:36:14,789] {dag_processing.py:627} INFO - Started a process (PID: 5425) to generate tasks for /mnt/var/airflow/dags/bin/prod/daily_agent_email_dag.py - logging into /mnt/var/airflow/l
Oct 30 18:36:14  airflow[4742]: [2017-10-30 18:36:14,831] {jobs.py:1000} INFO - No tasks to send to the executor
Oct 30 18:36:14  airflow[4742]: [2017-10-30 18:36:14,832] {jobs.py:1443} INFO - Heartbeating the executor
Oct 30 18:36:14  airflow[4742]: [2017-10-30 18:36:14,833] {jobs.py:1195} INFO - Executor reports user_presence_raw_etl.transform_raw_user_presence execution_date=2017-10-30 14:00:00 as failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your sysconfig file is clobbering the `$PATH` environment variable, hence the error:

```
Oct 30 18:36:13  airflow[4742]: /bin/sh: 1: exec: bash: not found
```

Try setting that line to the following:

```
PATH=/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/envs/airflow_env/bin/airflow:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you installed airflow as a user other than airflow. I have a `airflow-scheduler.service` file that specifies the user that I used to install airflow as, in my case, `mghen`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow scheduler daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=mghen
Group=mghen
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/airflow scheduler
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I fought with a similar issue but didn't see this same error message. Anyway, maybe changing the `User` and `Group` might help. Since you specify an absolute path when you start airflow (`ExecStart=/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/envs/airflow_env/bin/airflow scheduler`) it makes it look like it's starting fine as the `airflow` user but really that `airflow` user can't actually run `airflow` the program because another user installed it. Idk how to fix the `PATH` I just changed `User` and `Group` in my `airflow-*.service` files.

Alternatively, perhaps you can install `airflow` as the `airflow` user so it's available in the `airflow` user's `PATH`.

Comment: This comment helped me debug my issue. I installed `airflow` as one user and configured systemd to run with `airflow` user

Answer (score 0):

Workers processes spawned by LocalExecutor cannot run airflow since it's not available in `PATH`. You only configure it for `sysconfig`. In example provided in airflow repository, [airflow-scheduler.service](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/scripts/systemd/airflow-scheduler.service) they expect airflow to be executable for a user.

My suggestion is to create virtualenv for airflow, install airflow there and then activate it for each shell where you want to run something related to airflow e.g. workers, scheduler or webserver.

Comment: Yes, I have an environment (anaconda). Typically I run airflow by creating a screen, then source activate airflow_env, then airflow scheduler. This works 100% of the time. My .service file is pointing to the virtual environment - perhaps it isn't being activated? What should I alter?

Comment: You can see in my example, the service file points to the sysconfig file which points to PATH=/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/envs/airflow_env/bin/airflow. That is the anaconda path that I normally run scheduler with on a screen.

Comment: Can you try to symlink `/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/envs/airflow_env/bin/airflow` into directory which exists in `$PATH` e.g. `/usr/local/bin`? Just to confirm that once the airflow is executable everything works as expected. Afterwards, we can focus on how to fix it for your service definition.

Comment: I added the symlink,  ERROR - failed to execute task Command 'exec bash -c 'airflow run ... dag.py'' returned non-zero exit status 127.:. That is the error I am getting now in journalctl. This is a different error which is promising.